# Why does my query, which contains a sql file as the command text, timeout?

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout, mysql-connector

In my application I am trying to populate a database with tables using a sql dump file. Before populating the database, I first create the database followed by a use command to select the created database. For that, I saved the file as a string resource and used it as the command's text. The used connection string contains the server ip, a user with all required privileges and the corresponding password as well as the database name.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();

        using (var transAction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = transAction;
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                try
                {

                    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS database;"
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    cmd.CommandText = "USE database;"
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    cmd.CommandText = Properties.Resources.database;
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                    await transAction.CommitAsync();
                }
                catch(MySqlException e)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        await transAction.RollbackAsync();
                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }

                    throw;  
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is my sql file:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


CREATE TABLE `filelog_entries` (
  `filelog_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `end_of_write_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `size` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `logspace_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `language_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `language_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `language_short_name` varchar(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `languages` (`language_id`, `language_name`, `language_short_name`) VALUES
(1, 'English', 'EN');

CREATE TABLE `logspaces` (
  `logspace_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `server_directory` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `client_directory` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `main_entries` (
  `log_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `application` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pc` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `message_archive` (
  `text_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(1000) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `tag_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `tag_affiliations` (
  `log_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `textlog_entries` (
  `textlog_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('DEBUG','INFO','WARNING','ERROR','METHOD','FILE') NOT NULL,
  `text_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `method` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `associated_file_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `associated_file_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `variable_data_affiliations` (
  `variable_data_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `variable_data_content` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `textlog_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `index_in_data` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `filelog_entries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`filelog_entry_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `file_name_logspace_unique` (`file_name`,`logspace_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `logspace_id` (`logspace_id`);
ALTER TABLE `filelog_entries` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `file_name` (`file_name`);

ALTER TABLE `languages`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `language_name_short_name_unique` (`language_name`,`language_short_name`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `languages` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `name_shortname` (`language_name`,`language_short_name`);

ALTER TABLE `logspaces`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`logspace_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `server_directory_unique` (`server_directory`) USING BTREE,
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `client_directory_unique` (`client_directory`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `logspaces` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `server_client_dir_and_user` (`server_directory`,`client_directory`,`user_name`);

ALTER TABLE `main_entries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`log_entry_id`);
ALTER TABLE `main_entries` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `application_pc` (`application`,`pc`);

ALTER TABLE `message_archive`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`text_id`,`language_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `content_unique` (`content`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `language_id` (`language_id`);
ALTER TABLE `message_archive` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `content` (`content`);

ALTER TABLE `tags`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `tag_name_unique` (`tag_name`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `tags` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `tag_name` (`tag_name`);

ALTER TABLE `tag_affiliations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`log_entry_id`,`tag_id`),
  ADD KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`);

ALTER TABLE `textlog_entries`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`textlog_entry_id`),
  ADD KEY `text_id` (`text_id`),
  ADD KEY `associated_file_id` (`associated_file_id`),
  ADD KEY `deleted` (`associated_file_deleted`);
ALTER TABLE `textlog_entries` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `method` (`method`);

ALTER TABLE `variable_data_affiliations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`variable_data_id`,`textlog_entry_id`,`index_in_data`),
  ADD KEY `textlog_entry_id` (`textlog_entry_id`);
ALTER TABLE `variable_data_affiliations` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `variable_data_content` (`variable_data_content`);


ALTER TABLE `languages`
  MODIFY `language_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `logspaces`
  MODIFY `logspace_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `main_entries`
  MODIFY `log_entry_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `message_archive`
  MODIFY `text_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `tags`
  MODIFY `tag_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `variable_data_affiliations`
  MODIFY `variable_data_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


ALTER TABLE `filelog_entries`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `filelog_entries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`filelog_entry_id`) REFERENCES `main_entries` (`log_entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `filelog_entries_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`logspace_id`) REFERENCES `logspaces` (`logspace_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `message_archive`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `message_archive_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `languages` (`language_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `tag_affiliations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tag_affiliations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`log_entry_id`) REFERENCES `main_entries` (`log_entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tag_affiliations_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`tag_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `textlog_entries`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `textlog_entries_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`textlog_entry_id`) REFERENCES `main_entries` (`log_entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `textlog_entries_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`associated_file_id`) REFERENCES `filelog_entries` (`filelog_entry_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `textlog_entries_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`text_id`) REFERENCES `message_archive` (`text_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `variable_data_affiliations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `variable_data_affiliations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`textlog_entry_id`) REFERENCES `textlog_entries` (`textlog_entry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

When debugging, the execution of the query takes a very long time. So long that it actually exceeds the default command timeout of 30 seconds. After the 30 seconds passed, I get a `MySqlException` stating that "The Command Timeout expired before the operation completed." Even increasing the timeout to values up to 60 seconds didn't bring any changes. 
Nevertheless, after cancelling the debugging process it turned out that the database has actually been populated with all the tables, indexes, constraints and even that one dataset specified in the sql file. That's why I assume that there is a problem with cancelling the execution of the command.

The sql file was created with help of the export function of phpMyAdmin. To connect to the database in my application, I am using the MySql Connector/NET version 0.61.0.

EDIT: I modified the file and added the `ALTER TABLE` commands one at a time. It turned out that the execution still took very long, but it still executed within the 60 seconds timeout I configured. When increasing the timeout to 80 seconds it turned out that the whole file could be executed as a command, because it took around 62 seconds. Just a bit longer than the maximum timeout I used.

So, why does it take so long? Is there any overhead I could probably reduce to make the execution faster?

Comment: Have you tried removing parts of the query in your sql file to see if it is a particular command that is causing the delay? Maybe delete all of the ALTER TABLE commands & check if all tables are created - then add each of the ALTER TABLE commands one at a time. I would also consider altering the 'languages' table before inserting into it.

Comment: I just noticed that I specified the wrong maximum timeout I tested the scenario with. It was meant to be 60 seconds. I also did what you recommended and added the ALTER TABLE commands one at a time. It turned out that the command took very long to execute, but it was still successful within the command timeout time. That's why I timed the execution time and increased the timeout and it turned out that the whole file as a command executes successfully in 62 seconds, a bit longer than the maximum timeout I used. Why does it take so long? Is there any overhead I don't need and could turn off?

Comment: Time taken does seem a bit long. The code I have to recreate a database (25+ mostly empty tables some with small amounts of data) performs all the actions to create autoincrement primary keys, indexes & constraints all within the 'CREATE TABLE' command & runs very quickly. Is there a reason for creating a basic tables & then using 2 ALTER commands on each  - it could be that adds significant time.

Comment: I ran your sample code and SQL statement locally with a MySQL Docker container and it took 5.6 seconds. I'm not sure why it's taking over ten times longer for you.

Comment: @PaulF The ALTER TABLE commands were generated by the export function of phpMyAdmin. I deleted them and put the contraints, the index and the primary key defintions directly into the CREATE TABLE command. The command execution now takes around 10 seconds, so it seems the ALTER TABLE commands produce a great overhead. Why is that? And why does it still take 10 seconds? Is there anything else I can improve or maybe change concerning the settings of my MariaDB server?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know enough about the inner workings of the server - maybe the result of the requirement to lock tables multiple times - adding the constraints is needing to lock all tables not just the table the command refers to.

Comment: In the code generated by mySql workbench export - the following commands are performed at the start _"SET OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL'"_ & at the end reset the original values _"SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;"_   It maybe disabling the requirement for foreign key & unique checks may improve things even if there is no data in the tables.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have put these into my file. Unfortunately, the execution time stays the same. I'll see if there are any other things I can do to improve the execution time.